# How to iterate on a subset of an STL Map in C++

Tags: c++, loops, dictionary, stl, iterator

I don't understand how to iterate only on a portion of an Stl map and not from begin to end like in standard traversate. Here is my code:

```
    auto end = temp_map.rbegin() + THRESHOLD_NUM;

    for (auto rit = temp_map.rbegin(); rit != end; ++rit)
    {
        int s = rit->second;

        for (int k = 0; k < MAX_ROWS; k++)
        {
            array_dist_it[k] = abs(input[k] - input_matrix[k][s]);
        }

        float av_real = mean(MAX_ROWS, array_dist_it);

        float score_real = score_func(av_real);

        rank_function(score_real, s);
    }
}
```

I think that the problem is related to the syntax of the for loop and in particular to the iterator. The error is about an invalid operator.

Comment: This isn't a crowdsourced debugging platform. Have you run through the possibilities? What do _you_ think is wrong? What have you tried in order to fix it? What other approaches do you reckon might work? Did you try those? What research material have you studied, and why do you think the approaches recommended therein are not appropriate solutions for your situation? Stack Overflow is not a replacement for *thought*; at least, it damned well shouldn't be.

Comment: "there is something wrong" What is wrong?

Comment: sorry if I have explained myself badly, clearly I have tried all the possibilities that came to my mind , the error is of course linked to the iterator. I'm not here to justify myself but to ask for solutions with you. Obviously I've searched for others possibilities before asking. I don't fully understand your point. If for you my question is trivial is another point.

Comment: We can't see how this "clearly doesn't work" unless you either provide an exact error message or output demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `std::map` has a [BidirectionalIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BidirectionalIterator).  It supports incrementing and decrementing but not addition or subtraction.  If you need to advance and iterator N times then you can use [`std::next`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next).  Using that instead of

```
auto end = temp_map.rbegin() + THRESHOLD_NUM;
```

You would have

```
auto end = std::next(temp_map.rbegin(), THRESHOLD_NUM);
```

Comment: Click on your own link: `std::advance` has `void` return type. Also, tsk tsk answering off-topic questions (though this one could potentially be made acceptable (if trivial) with an MCVE).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I used the wrong function and I corrected the answer to use `std::next`.  As far as the rest goes it is completely obvious that `auto end = temp_map.rbegin() + THRESHOLD_NUM;` is an error.

Comment: How obvious it is is irrelevant. We're trying to build quality Q&A here not take FGITW potshots at guessing obvious flaws in code presented in off-topic questions where the OP hasn't even written out the error message. This question is not searchable in the slightest, so it does not count as "useful" on Stack Overflow... and, thus, shouldn't be encouraged through being guess-answered. / Thanks for fixing your proposed solution.